# phpmail function not sending to office365

Tags: php, office365, phpmailer, sendmail

I have a php mail function which works for all emails (gmail, zoho and others) except the one which is setup with office365.

This is the php email code:

```
<?php
$to = "me@mydomain.com";
$subject = "Test Subject";
$txt = "Hello world!";
$headers = "From: hello@gmail.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC: anotherme@mydomain.com";

mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

Whenever, I set the "to" field to gmail and other domains (setup with gmail app or zoho), it works but when I set the "to" field to a domain setup with Office365, it doesn't reach the inbox.

I don't see any error log either. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Perhaps it´s a SPAM related Problem? you can test with tools like: https://www.mail-tester.com/?lang=en

Comment: Maybe Office365 have their mail server correctly setup, to reduce spam etc? If a mail server is "correctly" (in my opinion) setup, the emails needs to be sent from an allowed server. Check out: [DKIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail), for example. It tells you more about what I mean.

Comment: Check the inbox of the mail account your sending the mail from. Probably office365 Domains reject your mail (see comment from @Magnus Eriksson) or consider it to be spam.

Comment: Any idea how to check the log file? I'm using godaddy.

Comment: I can't possibly check the inbox of the users visiting my website!!! Most of them uses gmail.